# Determining whether a call to `registerUserNotificationSettings` has ever been made in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, notifications, uilocalnotification

I’m wanting to determine if a user has ever received an alert requesting to `registerUserNotificationSettings` `UIUserNotificationSettings`.

As an example, when accessing Photos, it’s possible to determine if there has been a request to access Photos and permission granted `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()`. It returns the status as `.Authorized`, `.Denied`, `.Restricted`, `.NotDetermined`. When there has been no requests to date, **`.NotDetermined`** is returned.

Similarly, when registering notifications and getting permission to do so from the user for the first time `UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings`, it is possible to determine types of notifications registered, `.Badge`, `.Alert`, `.Sound`, `.None`. (Note: `.None` can mean both there has been no request *or* that there has been a request, but the user has elected for no notifications.)

> Question:
>
> ***But*** is there a way to determine whether the `registerUserNotificationSettings` **has ever** been called before?
>   i.e. is there an equivalent to Photos `.NotDetermined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `registerUserNotificationSettings`, the `UIApplicationDelegate` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

will be called letting you know the result. Use this method to save relevant state information so the next time the app runs, you know whether it has been called before or not.

Comment: On a related note, what about if the relevant state information was never saved previously. What would be the approach be then to determine the state?

Comment: If there's no relevant state info saved then you know `didRegister` was never called which means that `registerUserNotificationSettings` was never called which means you now know that you must call it.